# jQuery show child in hidden parent, setting display property incorrectly

Tags: jquery, css, dom, show-hide

Please see the following jsfiddle for a demonstration:

http://jsfiddle.net/Drb8s/

The problem appears to occur when you use jQuery show() on an element that is within a hidden parent. (then subsequently show the parent). If the child element is `display: table` originally, when you call show() it switches it back to display: block which is incorrect.

I can only replicate this using the console in the fiddle, however in my app, I'm experiencing this issue via code.

HTML:

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">Inner</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.outer {
  display: none;
}
.inner {
  display: table;
}​
```

JS:

```js
$('.inner').hide();
// $('.inner').show();​​​  // this works in jsfiddle (but not in my app, or run through console)
```

**EDIT:** As a workaround I'm using `.css('display', 'table')` but I was just wondering if anyone knows the actual cause of this.

Answer (score 1):

`.show` and `.hide` are brutal in their methods of showing/hiding; you can't use them if you want specific, nontraditional styles:

```
$(".inner").data('oldstyle', $(".inner").css('display')).css('display', 'none');
...
$(".inner").css('display', $(".inner").data('oldstyle'));
```

Comment: thanks mate. just wondering if this is a bug in jquery, or a problem with the way I'm doing things. trying to understand the WHY better.

Comment: @captainclam jQuery uses an internal function css_defaultDisplay to determine the display style of the hidden element by creating an element in the DOM and seeing the default display that the browser gives to it.